# Can i send data to Intent.ACTION_CALL?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am a new android developer. can i send data to Intent.ACTION_CALL ?
My code is below

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_number));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
callIntent.putExtra("flag",1);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

The action of the Receiver is android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE. How can i get the flag value in onReceive() of the BroadcastReceiver ?

Please help me out .

Comment: please check my ans @manjari

Answer (score 0):

try this create one class

```
 public class example
{
 public static boolean data;
 public static String strData = "";
}
```

now create a Intent like this

```
String uri = "tel:"+my_name;
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
    example.data = true; /*see change, set data in Constants.data*/
    example.str = "Hello world..."; /*see change*/
    callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    _context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Now in broadcast receiver see the changes done...

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(bundle != null && example.data) { /*changes done, get boolean from the Constants.data*/
        Log.e("hi i have recieve",example.str);//print recieved data
    } 

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) { 
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver**Call State=" + state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            if(recieveCall){

            }
            Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver**Idle");
        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) { 

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) { 
        // Outgoing call
        String outgoingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver **Outgoing call " + outgoingNumber);

        setResultData(null); // Kills the outgoing call

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"PhoneStateReceiver **unexpected intent.action=" + intent.getAction());
    }
      }
}
```

Comment: i tried and it will get Log.e("hi i have recieve",example.str); for all outgoing call